# Heroku pg:pull style database replication on private stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, replication

What would be a good way to replicate "Heroku pg:push/pull" style turn-key database replication on a private stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do what pg:push/pull is doing: a pg_dump piped to a pg_restore. See the [source code here].[1](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb#L34)

Comment: Wasn't aware they had open sourced their scripts. Thanks for the link.